# Proof check. There is no set containing all abelian groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-set-theory, abelian-groups

Let $X$ be an infinite set and $Y$ be the set of finite subsets of $X$. Show that there
is a bijective map from $X$ to $Y$ . Show that $(Y, \Delta)$ is an abelian group (where $\Delta$ is symmetric difference.) Use it to show
that every nonempty set can be given an abelian group structure. Deduce that there
is no set containing all abelian groups. 
I think I have proved, what was asked in above question, but am not 100% sure, mostly in part 3,4, (though I have added other part in case, i have done something wrong. First part is already known to me as it is available on this site as well)

1. $Y = \{Z \subset X : |Z| < \infty  \}$. We need to show that $|X| = |Y|$. I was able to prove this when $X$ is countable. Though I was not able to prove it in general, but was able to get the same result on this site.
2. Since $Y \subset P(X)$, and $(P(X), \Delta)$ is indeed an Abelian group, so we just need to check the closure property and existence of inverse. Since $B \in Y $ is its own inverse, and for $B, C \in Y$, $|B \Delta C| \leq |B|+|C|$ so is finite and and hence an element of $Y$. Hence the claim.
3. Let $X\neq \varnothing$.
   Case 1. $X$ is finite. 
   In this case we have say, $X = \{x_{0},x_{1}, \cdots x_{n-1}\}$. Define $\star:X \times X \to X$ as $x_{i} \star x_{j} = x_{(i+j) \,\text{mod(n)}}$, where $i \in \{0,1, \cdots n-1 \}$ and, Clearly here, we have $x_{i}\star x_{j} = x_{j} \star x_{i}$ also, $x_0$ is identity element and $x_{n - i}$ is inverse of $x_{i}$ (where $x_n = x_0$). 

   Case 2. $X$ is infinite.  
   Let, $f: X \to Y$ be a bijection from $X$ to $Y$ which exists because of part 1. Define $\star: X \times X \to X$ as follows, for $a, b \in X$, $a \star b = f^{-1}(f(a) \Delta f(b))$, which is an element of $X$, and $f^{-1}$ exists and is bijection, so well defined binary map. 
   **Existence of Identity** 
   Since $f$ is bijection, so there exists $a_0 \in X$ such that $f(a_0) = \varnothing$ (Since $\varnothing \in Y$). This $a_0$ is identity element, since $a \star a_0 = f^{-1}(f(a) \Delta f(a_0)) = f^{-1}(f(a)\Delta \varnothing) = f^{-1}(f(a)) = a$. 
   **Inverse** 
   $a$ is self inverse, since $a \star a = f^{-1}(f(a) \Delta f(a)) = f^{-1}(\varnothing) = a_0$.
   **Associativity** 
   It follows since $(a \star b) \star c = f^{-1}(f(a) \Delta f(b)) \star c = f^{-1}(f(f^{-1}(f(a) \Delta f(b)))\Delta f(c)) = f^{-1}((f(a) \Delta f(b))\Delta f(c)) = f^{-1}(f(a)\Delta (f(b)\Delta f(c))) = a \star f^{-1}(f(b) \Delta f(c)) = a \star (b \star c)$. 
   **Commutativity** 
   Finally since $a \star b = f^{-1}(f(a) \Delta f(b)) = f^{-1}(f(b) \Delta f(a)) = b \star a$, hence $\star$ is commutative.
4. For this I thought since, every set can be given a Abelian structure, so if such a set exists, it will contain all sets. And we know, set of all sets dose not exists, so set of all Abelian group dosent exists.